# How can I enable deployment of individual Lambda functions using Terraform?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

I'm working on automating deployment of Lambda functions using Terraform. The goal is to be able to deploy either a single Lambda function or all of the functions in the repo. I'm able to deploy a number of functions from a structure that looks like:

```
├── README.md
├── js
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── jsFunction1/
│   │   └── main.tf
│   └── jsFunction2/
│       └── main.tf
├── py
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── pyFunction1/
│   │   └── main.tf
│   └── pyFunction2/
│       └── main.tf
└── terraform
    ├── README.md
    ├── common/
    ├── global/
    ├── main.tf
    ├── modules/
    ├── prod/
    └── stage/
```

The goal is to be able to deploy `js/jsFunction1` independently (without building packages for any other functions) while also having `terraform/main.tf` able to deploy all the lambda functions in the repository (after they've been built). This is so a developer can update the stage deployment with changes to an individual function without concern that they might have an improper version of a function that the developer isn't working on.

What I was hoping to do is create a back-end for each Lambda function so that the developer can use `terraform apply` from within the source folder. I don't see how to import the state of the Lambda functions that were deployed from the `terraform/` module. Can you tell me if importing the state of the resources is a reasonable approach or recommend a better way to achieve the ability to deploy one of many Lambda functions?

Here is the `main.tf` from `js/jsFunction1`

```
module "jsFunction1" {
  source                        = "../../terraform/modules/lambda"
  source_path                   = "${path.module}/dist"
  lambda_function_name          = "jsFunction1"
  lambda_handler                = "lambdaAdapter.handler"
}
```

There is a similar `main.tf` in each of the folders under `js` and `py`. This is `main.tf` from the `terraform` folder

```
module "jsFunction1" {
    source = "./../js/jsFunction1"
}

module "jsFunction2" {
    source = "./../js/jsFunction2"
}

module "pyFunction1" {
    source = "./../py/pyFunction1"
}

module "pyFunction2" {
    source = "./../py/pyFunction2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use [lambda package module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/v1.31.0/examples/build-package/main.tf) to zip seperate packages for specific lambda's and deploy them.

The package module has the ability to build the package only if change is happened in the respective folders.

So you can have a single main.tf and the reference the output values from package module.

Comment: Yes. That is what `terraform/main.tf` is for. The challenge is when developers are working on a particular function, say `jsFunction1`. The build of `jsFunction2` may be behind the last version that was deployed, but it will be deployed (overwriting the newer version), because it is changed relative to the state in the back-end. At least that appears to be what's happening.